# Is there anyway to send someone a password that they can use but cannot see?

Tags: php, mysqli, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

Just trying to hack together a simple script, and I had a little question about passwords.

Is there anyway I can send someone a random password that they cannot see themselves but can use to say, change their facebook password to in order to block themselves from logging in? I will then send them the visible password at a specified time later on.

This is for purely educational purposes, as I'm just building little apps here and there to learn php and mysql.

Example: Friend wants to get off facebook for 3 hours. He uses web app and I email him a randomly generated password for him to change his current FB password to. However, on the email it is hidden to him. After 3 hours, he gets another email allowing him to use it.

I  understand there might be some easier ways / clearer methods of achieving my end goal, but I am just curious about this itself!

Thanks so much

Comment: you don't send a password. you send over some encrypted/hashed value and use that value as a one-time "password" that expires as soon as it's used - just like in most password reset emails. "click here within X hours to reset...".

Comment: You could generate a random string that points to a random password. So, the user only sees the first random string

Comment: It'd be better that your webapp talks directly to facebook and changes the password, then 3 hours later sends the user the password so they can get back on.  Or change the password back.

Comment: Let me give you a piece of advice: **NEVER MEDDLE WITH USER PASSWORDS**. Ever. Just leave passwords alone. If you don't want police at your door. It is not a chindren's game. Passwords are not for this purpose

Comment: @marcb wow how did I not think of that haha thank you. Do you have any places I might be able to read about on how to get started?

Comment: @keith I've done some research on that and apparently it is now against their TOS to collect login info, hence why I resorted to my original idea. But thank you for your consideration

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the fair warning. Not looking to have this go public. Just want to experiment with maybe myself to see if I can hack together some script to learn from.

Comment: **WHATEVER** you call it in easy terms, it would be crime. Leave. Other people's passwords. Alone.

Comment: I can't believe I see such a conversation here. One would be beaten to a pulp if mention humble md5() to hash a password. At the same time everyone is so eager to discuss just giving their account away.

Comment: @YourCommonSense He's being curious. So what. He's putting together a small script for himself.

Comment: @relentless With computer crime it gets all federal and stuff... get the wrong judge on the wrong day and you will find yourself much poorer and some inmates sex toy for just being curious, not to mention finding a job in computers afterwards being kind of hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending an e-mail that contains "something" that allows the user to log in with, you are sending them a password and if it's clickable/copyable from the e-mail, they will see it. Regardless of if the password is plain text that directly matches a stored value (like "thi$ismyPa$$word") or some other encrypted value that when inputted is decrypted to match a stored value is irrelevant, the user either way knows what that value is (because they have to enter it). In order for the user to provide a value, they have to have the value. As others have mentioned, you could implement a one-time use password into your application, but that wouldn't work for a facebook implementation because it's not your app and you can't control it's functionality. The short answer, if you provide something to the user (like an e-mail) that is used to access a system, then they can see the value(s) necessary to login.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach is to calculate a hash sum of some kind from the password, and send that.   Thre are one-way algorithms, like MD5, that can do this.   That way, conformance TO the password can be assured, without having to send the password itself, or from which the password can be inferred.

For even greater security, both a hash and a checksum can be sent:  that way the hash itself cannot be intercepted and sent as a proxy for the password:  authentication will not happen unless both the hash and the checksum values agree.